# pattern with at least 8 characters/uppercase/number

Tags: regex, symfony, validation, fosuserbundle

currently I'm using symfony2 and I need a pattern with condition:
-min 8 characters, max 20 characters
-must contain 1 letter at least
-must contain 1 number at least
-may contain special characters like !@#$%^&*()_+
I tried this code but it doen't work :

```
/**
 * Encrypted password. Must be persisted.
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern     = "/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[?!-‌​/_/=:;§]).{8,20}+$/i",
 *     htmlPattern="/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[?!-‌​/_/=:;§]).{8,20}$/",
 *     match=true,
 *     message="message error ")
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $password;
```

Comment: "-min 8 characters, max 8 characters", so 8 characters long?

Comment: sorry max 20 characters

Comment: Try [`"/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*()_+]).{8,20}$/i"`](https://regex101.com/r/agPJXX/2) Please explain what "it doen't work" means.

Comment: means that even if I put 1 character, no error message shown after submitting

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like that?

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern = "/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]+){8,20}$"/",
 * 
 * rest of options...
 *
 * )
 */
```

Comment: I tried to test it using _'testTEST6?!'_ but I still got error password doesn't match pattern

Comment: Yes... `?` is not allowed in the above regex.

Comment: Add special character: `pattern = "/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9!?@#$%^&*()_]+){8,20}$"/"`

Comment: it returns :

    This value is not valid.

Comment: is `match=true` in your Assert\Regex options?

Comment: are the simple quote part of your password?

Comment: I can avoid adding quote

Comment: So, try to open a regex online tool to check what is wrong... https://regex101.com/ When I test this pattern `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9!?@#$%^&*()_]+){8,20}$` with `testTEST6?!`, it works...

Comment: I don't know why it returns " This value is not valid" even the entered text fit the pattern (I test it using online regex ) should I use a specific format in this case or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank yoou so much for your answer .
I had to override regex for  `$plainPassword` instead of `$password` because I'm using FOSuserBundle .